# How to tell the server application is deleted or uninstalled from iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I Inform the server application is uninstalled or deleted from the iPhone. So that it delete all the event recorded by the server.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? Sometimes my 2 yr. old daughter accidentally deletes apps from my phone. Usually I can re-install and all my cloud data is still readily available. I would be displeased if it were not this way.

Comment: Ya at the time of deletion, I want to delete all the events recorded or register on the server...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. Definitely NOT from code (your app is not running when deleted).

Unless Apple provides this functionality, for example as a notification/e-mail to the developer (They Don't right now), it is impossible to know. Don't hold your breath...

Answer (score 2):

Well, your server can run a purge routine to check if a user hasn't made traffic for the last x monthes or so... if so delete his records. (It will be wise to inform the users of this of course)